# Ormlite with MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, ormlite

I'm developing android app that needs a DB. I had experience with Hibernate but I didn't try it because I'm hearing that it's too much for android.

I followed this nice tutorial [1] to setup ormlite with sqlite. But I need to use a real DB like MySQL. Is there any good tutorial out there for using MySQL with ormlite?

1. http://logic-explained.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-ormlite-in-android-projects.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any good tutorial out there for using MySQL with ormlite?

No, but you can look at the `HelloAndroidH2` example program which uses JDBC on Android to connect to a H2 database:

> http://ormlite.com/android/examples/

Instead of using the ormlite-core and ormlite-android packages, you would use the ormlite-core and ormlite-jdbc packages.  In the example program you can see:

```
connectionSource =
    new JdbcConnectionSource(
            "jdbc:h2:/data/data/helloandroidh2/databases/helloAndroidH2");
```

That JDBC URI stores the H2 database on the local Android storage.  Instead, you'd use something like the following as your database URI:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-database-host/my-database-name
```

One thing that worries me with this method is that JDBC is not officially supported by Android.  You might find things working fine until the next Android code release.  Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks man. After a day of trying different things, I could get it to work. The only thing that I'm not completely sure at this point is that I don't know what to do with connectionSource. Should I close it once in a while and re-open it again and submit my transactions in a batch like mode? or I can keep it open all the time, like the way it's implemented in the example code.

Comment: I'd keep it open @Mohammad.  You can use the batch methods in the ORMLite DAO or the `TransactionManager` to turn off/on auto-commit and do a whole bunch of operations at once.  Otherwise I'd leave it on.